# iTunes Connect - Not able to create an iTunes Connect record

Tags: app-store-connect

I have a `Xamarin.iOS` app and I'm trying to upload it to TestFlight. So, I am trying to add create an iTunes Connect record. When I log into iTunes Connect, I am being displayed the following page.

[image]

When I click on **Apps**, the following page is displayed, even though I am registered for a Apple Developer program and signed in to that account.

[image]

So I cannot proceed with the steps in the [following link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/testflight?tabs=vsmac) and cannot add a iTunes Connect record.

Could you please tell me why I am not being redirected to the correct page to continue with the process?

Comment: you need to login at https://itunesconnect.apple.com/login not in https://developer.apple.com

Comment: @SagarBhut Yes, that's where I am logged in. But I'm being redirected to `developer.apple.com` when clicked on **Apps** in `itunesconnect.apple.com`

Comment: On the top right corner still you would be able to see the Enrol button to proceed enrolment. It seems you haven't been enrolled yet. are you using your own account with paid $99 ?

Comment: @Sathish not my own account but my company's. My account is set as an admin in theirs. They have a paid subscription

Comment: @Curiousity that is not possible to you login in iTunes and redirect to you developer canter.

Comment: @SagarBhut I'm afraid that's what happening though...

Comment: @Curiousity Please check with your company's account that you have been invited for itunesconnect as well.

Comment: @Curiousity Since you don't have subscribed it should go to enrolment instead of different account that you are part of it. Make sure about under which team you are trying to clicks on the Myapp. If its yours definitely you won't be able to get in to MyApps until you enrol for itunesconnect. Cheers!

Comment: @Sathish so I should ask the company to send me an invitation to add me as an admin to iTunes Connect and also after that, I have to enroll as I did for the developer account? Or else, after I accept the invitation, will I be able to use iTunes Connect correctly? After accepting the invitation, what do I have to do?

Comment: @Curiousity Yes, you can access iTunesConnect once you accepted the invitation. After accepted you can login with itunesconnect and change your team to your company account then go for myApps page Cheers!

Comment: @Sathish It worked. Thanks a lot. Will you be able to add this as an answer so that I can mark it as the answer? :D

Comment: @Curiousity Cool! just done..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have subscribed it should go to enrolment instead of different account that you are part of it. Make sure about under which team you are trying to clicks on the Myapps. If its your's definitely you won't be able to get in to MyApps until you enrol for itunesconnect.

Please check with your company's account that you have been invited for itunesconnect as well.

You can access iTunesConnect once you accepted your company's invitation. After accepted that you shall login with itunesconnect and change your team to your company account then go for myApps page. Cheers!